# Automated a minipage+fcolorbox with a newenvironment

Tags: environments, minipage, colorbox

How could I create a new environment to automated the following code?

```
\noindent\fcolorbox{white}{lightgray}{ \begin{minipage}{0.96\textwidth}
 some text in here
\end{minipage} }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Stupid question: if you make the frame white, why using a framed colour box in the first place and not a `\colorbox`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simple new command can also do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \noindent%
    \fcolorbox{white}{lightgray}{%
        \begin{minipage}{0.96\textwidth}
            #1
        \end{minipage}% 
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\foo{some text}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Needless to reinvent the wheel: you already have the `shaded(*)}` environment from the `framed` package. . Furthermore, these environments can break across pages. The `shaded*` environment makes the shaded area fit exactly the margin, whereas `shaded` makes the text justified between the margins and the shaded area overflows the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{white}{lightgray}{ \begin{minipage}{0.96\textwidth}
some text in here
\end{minipage}}
\begin{shaded}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{shaded}
\begin{shaded*}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{shaded*}

\end{document}
```

[image]